# Is there any way to take the stage snapshot in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, snapshot, stage

Cannot convert the stage as a bitmapData and draw it. Is there any way, please help me...Thanks

Comment: Embad, Welcome to SO. Please read first http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will read this..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ImageSnapshot](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html) class.

Also take a look at this [Turning an ImageSnapshot into an Image in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831514/turning-an-imagesnapshot-into-an-image-in-flex)